Calculating the odds of 3 sequential random numbers
What would be the odds or probability of
First: generating number 5 from numbers 1-28
Then: generating number 6 from numbers 1-28
Then: generating number 3 from numbers 1-15
Basically I’m trying to calculate the odds of generating a certain Bible verse of Acts 6:3, where the book of Acts is the 5th out of 28 books in the New Testament, then generating the 6th chapter out of 28 chapters from that book, then generating the 3rd verse out of 15 verses in that chapter. Thanks!

Define "random" in this context. Are all numbers from $1$ to $28$  and $1$ to $15$ equally likely to be chosen, or are the probabilities skewed in favour of certain numbers?

@H.sapiensrex Imagine just using a true random number generator to generate a number between 1-28 two different times and then generate another number between 1-15

Does that translate to a uniform distribution, or?...

Making the most natural assumptions, this would be $\frac 1{28}\times \frac 1{28}\times \frac 1{15}=\frac 1{11760}\sim 0.000085$.  Of course, changing the assumptions (which are very unclear) will change this result.

Even if you were to try to make a sensible definition of the problem you are trying to ask... why should it matter?  If this is based on a real world experience you had that you just so happen to open up to this verse..... coincidences happen all the time.  If you had not noticed or had this particular coincidence happen, surely there will have been some other coincidence that did happen.  There are zillions of opportunities for something interesting to happen.  It would be stranger if nothing remarkable happened at all.  Why should this particular coincidence even be considered remarkable?

Probability is the ratio of how many ways you can win divided by the total number of possible outcomes.  In this case, you have one "winning" set of numbers and
$28 \times 28 \times 15 = 11,760$ possible outcomes
I would say that the change of randomly hitting that one verse is
$P=\frac {1}{11,760}$
Meanwhile, that is if the numbers are chosen randomly with a uniform distribution.  If you were to open a New Testament "randomly" and stick in your finger, the sample will be biased because you will unconsciously pick a place somewhere in the middle so the chances of hitting a verse in Matthew or Revelations are quite low while that of Acts (1007 verses and at about 50% of the way through the 7,957 verses in the New Testament) are quite good.
